# Listview and Viewpager inside Popupwindow like My Places (Maps Android tablet)

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, popupwindow

can u guys do a favor for me? as i am in need for ur help. 
could u guys do an example of viewpager within a popupwindow like in the maps app(android tablet). as an example, once the Menu -> My Places was clicked, the My Places popupwindows will appear which contains the viewpager and listView such as Offline, Recent, and etc

[Click here to preview sample image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/88649068@N06/8086982650/in/photostream)